# Page style: adding numbers and name of chapter

Tags: header-footer

How can I get this on each page of my thesis?

[image]

Comment: What class are you using?

Comment: The class i’m using is BOOK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the use of `fancyhdr`. The code presented next will allow you to include desired text on the header.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textit{\chaptername \ \thechapter. #1}}{}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
 \fancyfoot[C]{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter[The hotel recommendation problem]{The hotel recommendation problem}
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

I have assumed you are using the `book` document class. Compiling the previous code will result in
[image: Chapter Description]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! There is on minor detail: in the screenshot, the header is in italic `textit{}`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Ok, now the text is italicized. If you think my answer meet your request please marked as the correct answer.